# What is the names of these two theorems?

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem 1:**

A topological space $(X, T)$ is regular if and only if $\forall x\in X, \forall u\in T \ni x\in u, \exists v\in T\ni x\in u ,\exists v\in T \ni x \in v \subseteq \bar{v}\subseteq u$

**Theorem 2:**

A topological space $(X, T)$ is normal if and only if $\forall F$ closed set and $\forall u$ open set $\ni F\subseteq u, \exists v \in T \ni x \in v \subseteq \bar{v}\subseteq u$

My teacher wrote the above two theroems yesterday. I have been looking for proof or some kind of a description for these theorem but couldn't find any. Does anyone know the name or the proof of these theorems?. Also, how do these two theorems relate to the definitions of regular space and open space.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

**Note:** there may be some mistakes in the theorems because I was in a rush when I wrote them.

Comment: Using $\ni$ to mean "such that" is in my opinion a bad idea at the best of times. Mixing it in a chain with $\in$ is horrible.

Comment: @DanielFischer, that is what my teacher uses not me.

Comment: I believe that. I still think it's a horrible idea.

Comment: I don't think these theorems have names, they're just rather straightforward rewritings of the definitions.

Comment: what's the role of $F$ in second theorem?

Comment: @user160738, I am not sure but I think it means that $u$ contains a closed set.

Comment: Just call them _ugly_,

Comment: @user60589, I would but that won't help me to understand them.

Comment: @MrDi try to write them down in a _nicer_ way. That should help.

Comment: @user60589, this is what my teacher wrote. Other than changing ∋ to "such that" I don't think I can make any further changes.

Comment: I'm sorry your teacher writes this way. I would call these "lemmas" or equivalent definitions rather than theorems.

Comment: For the translation between these theorems and the definitions, not that by taking the complement, you have a bijection between the family of open subsets containing $x$ resp. $F$, and the family of closed subsets disjoint from $\{x\}$ resp. $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no names for these theorems, and often these are taken as equivalent definitions of regularity/normality and are usually introducted right after their definitions.

As many people pointed out, your theorem is written in a rather odd form and is not easy to read. Hopefully I rewrote them in a more read-able forms

**Theorem 1**

$(X,T)$ is regular iff for every $x\in X$ and closed $C$ not containing $x$, there exist open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in U$, $C\subset V$, $U\cap V=\emptyset$. That is, they are separated by open sets.

Now suppose that $X$ is regular and $x\in X$, and let $U$ be open such that $x\in U$. Then $X\setminus U:=C$ is closed and does not contain $x$, so by regularity there are open sets $U',V'$ such that $x\in U'$ and $C\subset V'$ and $U'\cap V'=\emptyset$. Therefore, $U'\subset X\setminus V'$, and becuase $C=X\setminus U \subset V'$, it follows that $X\setminus V' \subset U$ so

$$
x\in U' \subset X\setminus V' \subset U
$$

Since $X\setminus V'$ is closed, it follows that $$x\in U' \subset \overline{U'} \subset X\setminus V'\subset U$$

---

Consversely, if $x\in X$ and $C$ is closed set not containing $x$ then $x\in X\setminus C$ and $X\setminus C$ is open, so there exist $x\in U \subset \overline{U} \subset X\setminus C$ and $U\in T$, so $U$ and $X\setminus \overline{U}$ separates $x$ and $C$.

---

**Theorem 2**

I suspect you meant $F\subset v \subset \overline{v} \subset u$ in your statment of theorem; otherwise $x$ popped up randomly and if one interprets it as $x\in F$ then this condtion is no different than one in **Theorem 1** but clearly normality and regularity are not equivalent in general.

Suppose that $X$ is normal. Let $F$ be closed and $U$ open such that $ F\subset U$

Since $X\setminus U$ is closed disjoint from $F$, normality implies that there are disjoint open $U',V'$ separating them, $F\subset U'$, $X\setminus U \subset V'$. By disjointedness, then $F\subset U' \subset X\setminus V' \subset U$ and as $X\setminus V'$ is closed, then we have

$$
F\subset U' \subset \overline{U'} \subset X\setminus V' \subset U$$

Conversely, let $C,D$ be disjoint closed sets in $X$. $X\setminus D$ is open set containing $C$, so by the condition assumed we can find open $U$ such that $C\subset U \subset\overline{U}\subset X\setminus D$. Then $U$ and $X\setminus \overline{U}$ are disjoint open sets separating $C,D$, so $X$ is normal.